# Vi/Vim editor enters next line instead of entering editor mode

Tags: bash, vim, bashrc

Recently, I noticed that when I type `vi foo.txt`, my mouse cursor will simply enter the next line without actually opening the file.

If it is a new file, I can enter Ctrl+C to enter the file and edit.
If it is a existing file, I simply just could not open it.

I have played around it for a while and searched on google but had no luck.

**What I have tried:**
the result of my `which vi` is the following: `/urs/bin/vi`

I have also checked `.bashrc` and `.vimrc`. The only change I made on `.bashrc` was the path to inferno OS. I recently installed Inferno operating system and have set the path variable. I am not sure if it has anything to do with it, but I doubt it.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is a dumb mistake I made.

I was playing around with Inferno's GUI and I set the `DISPLAY` variable in my .bashrc and I forgot about it.

As I removed that line, and it is working now.

Any explination will be helpful and appreciated.